# k8s 1.8 kubectl get nodes does not return controllers

Tags: kubernetes, controllers, kubectl

I am performing test migrations from k8s 1.7 to 1.8.  After I upgrade the workers and the controller managers I see that the output of `kubectl get nodes` only returns workers.  Previously, on k8s 1.7 a `kubectl get nodes` would return the workers and the controller managers.  I have tried this with the 1.7 and 1.8 version of kubectl.

I am not able to find anything in the 1.8 Changelog that states this output would change.

Is this expected output or is this a bug?  I have asked this twice in the Slack channel and have not gotten a reply so I am asking here.

Answer (score 1):

I had neglected to setup the kubeconfig flag for the kubelet wrapper in the controller setup.  The controller was never registering to the api server.  The --api-servers flag was deprecated in 1.8 and requires configuring the server in the kubeconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl get nodes` has only ever output Node API objects

Comment: How is a Node API object determined?  I wonder if there is a terminology difference here.  When I say controller I mean a controller manager.  I will update my question to be clearer.  Knowing that, what changed in 1.8 that the controller managers no longer show up when performing `kubectl get nodes`

Comment: `kubectl get nodes` has always displayed the output of the API call `/api/v1/nodes`, rendered nicely. That did not change in 1.8.

Comment: When I query `/api/v1/nodes` is that pulling the information out of etcd?  If not, where does it get the information when I query that API endpoint?